# Problem with CORS that happen only on IOS

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I'm testing my website on iOS 12.1.13 and i have run in to the problem with CORS request. It allways return error status: 0, but only on IOS for Safari and Chrome. On PC and MAC there is no problem on any browser. Requests from IOS don't reach backend, any idea why this happen?

code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: apiUrl,
    method: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Working!");
        followedContentGetDataSuccess(data);
        if (contentDataCache) {
            followedContentConfigurePager(contentDataCache.TotalSize, followedContentCurrentPage);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
        console.log('Error - ' + errorMessage);
        followedContentOnError(error);
    }
});
```

Request header from IOS:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the "Origin" header is malformed. The origin header is used for CORS so that's a good place to start.

Comment: `crossDomain: true` and `withCredentials: true`  why are you using these? Do you know what they do? `async: false`  this is unlikely to work since most browsers have deprecated / removed synchronous HTTP requests. Also, your `Accept` header doesn't look right. I would omit it.

Comment: I have removed Accept header and async: false - i didn't know that is deprecated thanks for that. `crossDomain: true` I'm using because this request is send to other domain and i manually set up to make sure that is allways true.   `withCredentials: true` i use because it's need credentials. On PC and MAC it's return 401 and that's what i want to happen on IOS to.  @JakeHolzinger thanks for that idea now i'm trying to find why this "Origin" header is malformed.

Comment: JQuery's `crossDomain` is practically useless (read the docs) and `withCredentials` only applies when your client has cookies for the API domain. I'm not saying you don't but cookie authentication for an API isn't very common